# How to change colour of selected cell in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am making an app in which I am showing my data in a `UITableView`. I am stuck. I want to change the colour of the selected cell. How to do this?

Below is my code in `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"the messageid==%@",[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] objectForKey:@"messageId"]);
    manage.messageid=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] objectForKey:@"messageId"];  // here i pass the value to singleton class
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:tableView];
}
```

Comment: if u click the cell u want to change the selection color

Comment: yeah i want to change on click event

Comment: use `UITableViewCell`'s `selectionStyle` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has two options for selection only `Blue` and another one is `Gray`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath 
{

   /// here your cell identifier name and details
 UIView *changeselectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
changeselectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(245.0/255.0) green:(245.0/255.0) blue:(245.0/255.0) alpha:1];   // change the RGB as you like
cell.selectedBackgroundView = changeselectionColor;

//...... here add your cell details.. //

}
```

or in another **choice no 2** call this method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 UIView * changeselectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
 changeselectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor GreenColor];
 cell.selectedBackgroundView = changeselectionColor;
}
```

Comment: @MishalAwan- mark this as your answer if it worked for you so that it helps other stack users too

Answer (score 3):

Update your code as mentioned below:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"the messageid==%@",[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] objectForKey:@"messageId"]);

    manage.messageid = [[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] objectForKey:@"messageId"];  // here i pass the value to singleton class

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:tableView];

    // Add this line to set selected default gray style
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
}
```

Use selectionStyle property to get cell highlighed. For more details refer [UITableViewCellSelectionStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellSelectionStyle)

Comment: @mrunerl -- if i like to change my selection color into **RED** or **orange**, how to use ..

Comment: Then I would use backgroundColor, thats why over code I have written its for default style. Also added link to check which other default styles available.

Comment: @Mrunal - i asked custom color

Comment: @MishalAwan- mark this as your answer if it worked for you so that it helps other stack users too

Answer (score 1):

May be this will be useful to u...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   UIView *selectedRowColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
   selectedRowColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedRowColor;
}
```